# EXCEL-compare two cells in two workbooks if matched copy other cell related to matched cell in to checked workbook cell

Tags: excel

I have two excel workbook and book1 has a column(Name) should match with book2 column(Name) and if matched then it should copy column2(address) from book1 and copy to the column2(address) of the book2. if nothing is matched leave it as it is.
if anyone can help me very much appreciated.

P.S. These two workbooks received from two different sources and have 1000 of rows and 10 or more columns so above is an example only without other columns.

Comment: You can do this with formula. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried using vlookup below is the method but have no luck
=VLOOKUP(Branch1!I3,MIS!L2:T15,3,FALSE)

Comment: I don't think it can be done by formula, because it would create Circular Reference problem. If you really want to copy these adresses into book2.column(address), then it has to be done via VBA or you can use formula, but in book2 create another helping column with IF function. You can copu values of the helping column and place it to the column Address.

Comment: @Srpic, Correct then it will create another column but then I have to delete it later on.  but again i have to search the values and paste right?

Answer (score 0):

If you create the helping column in the Book2, you can try following: `=IF((A2=[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!A2)=TRUE,[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!B2,B2)`

Modify the ranges, since I don't know where you have the data and spread the formula as you wished. If names are same, then it will copy address from Book1 and if not, it will copy address from Book2. Then you can copy and paste as values the helping column into the column with your addresses in Book2 and remove the helping one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it will not work I tried it and sometimes it works and sometimes not because data not in the same order in both files so it will mess up.

Comment: You should use combination of IF and VLOOKUP then. If you share the names of columns or more details, I can set it up.

Comment: Below are the sample header names and data I've extracted from the file 
Book1

Pax_no,          address,                                           name, 

A38432022, China,                                               TAN J,

N2996467,       116 FONGLE RD PANADURA,     TRAVELS, 







Book2

name,            address,                           pax_no

TRAVELS, 116,                                   N2996467, 

TAN J,                                                  A38432022,